# Which fragmentManager Should i use

Tags: android, android-fragments, datepicker, android-fragmentactivity

Im using fragments and tryng to make a form which i can get the date using datepicker for after store it in a database (There is not the problem now) The problem its i was following a guide to learn how to use the datepicker in fragments activity. And i got a pair of questions (And errors)
I've been using  [This guide](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.com/2012/10/creating-datepicker-using.html)

And im getting this error:

> "The method getSupportFragmentManager is undefined for the type"

i've read there is not getSupportFragmentManager in "Fragments" but they are in "FragmentActivity"

There is a equivalent in "Fragments" For this method? or what i should do.

I was searching and reading a lot of guides but this is the easily way that i found and have this problem.

I will post my Fragment class,fragment xml,and datepickerfragment

**FragmentClass (regventa_Fragment)..**

```
public class Regventa_Fragment extends Fragment  {
public Button guardar;
public Button fecha_button;

public Regventa_Fragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_regventa, container, false);

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Hola", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    guardar=(Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.guardar);
    //fecha_button=(Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.fecha_button);
    getView().findViewById(R.id.fecha_button).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
            showDatePicker();
           }

        private void showDatePicker() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
          });
}

private void showDatePicker() {
      DatePickerFragment date = new DatePickerFragment();
      /**
       * Set Up Current Date Into dialog
       */
      Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
      Bundle args = new Bundle();
      args.putInt("year", calender.get(Calendar.YEAR));
      args.putInt("month", calender.get(Calendar.MONTH));
      args.putInt("day", calender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
      date.setArguments(args);
      /**
       * Set Call back to capture selected date
       */
      date.setCallBack(ondate);
      date.show(getFragmentManager(), "Date Picker");
     }

     OnDateSetListener ondate = new OnDateSetListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
        int dayOfMonth) {
      }
     };
```

}

**fragment_regventa.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/guardar"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/guardar" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/borrar"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/borrar" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/fecha_button"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/fecha_venta"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="@string/fecha_button" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/regventa"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/comprador"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/comprador" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fecha_venta"
    style="android:editTextStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fecha_button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/comprador"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/fecha_venta"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="17sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/elevendidos"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/pesoventa"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pesoventa"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/elementos_vendidos"
    android:inputType="number" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/pesoventa"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/comprador"
    android:layout_below="@+id/fecha_button"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/pesoventa" />
```

**DatePicker Fragmentent**

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {
OnDateSetListener ondateSet;

public DatePickerFragment() {
}

public void setCallBack(OnDateSetListener ondate) {
ondateSet = ondate;
}

private int year, month, day;

@Override
public void setArguments(Bundle args) {
super.setArguments(args);
year = args.getInt("year");
month = args.getInt("month");
day = args.getInt("day");
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), ondateSet, year, month, day);
}
}
```

If i change from "Fragment" to "FragmentActivity" Thats going to works good? with the other fragments i have?.. Thanks

Comment: getSupportFragmentManager only works with classes inheriting FragmentActivity. If you want to use fragments then try to use getFragmentManager.

Answer (score 1):

`getSupportFragmentManager()` is meant for android support library

that means

if you are using support library you have to use `getSupportFragmentManager()`
else you have to use `getFragmentManager()`

to verify check your import

`import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`
means you using support library 
then you have to use `getSupportFragmentManager()`

`import android.app.Fragment`
means you are using the native library
then you have to use `getFragmentManager()`

Good Luck :)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I import this library                           import android.app.Fragment; And i modified the line in this way date.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "Date Picker");..   But now that says i need to created a method called show in the datepickerfragment.java what i should do?

Answer (score 1):

I solve the problem.. I was using

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

Instead of...

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

In DatepickerFragment.

After that i use...

```
date.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "Date Picker");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand the deference between FragmentActivity & Fragment. FragmentActivity is subclass of Activity & activity holds Fragment & two are different things. 
See the below links & look that fragment doesn't not inherit from Activity.

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

So, if you need to use getSupportFragmentManager() then first call the activity that holds the fragment & call the fragmentManager. like : `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()`

Another thing is if you use Fragment from support library then you get "`getSupportFragmentManager()`" other wise you get "`getFragmentManager()`"

Thanks

Comment: I import this library    import android.app.Fragment;    and i change the    getFragmentManager(); to    date.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "Date Picker");    And they IDE says i need no create a show method in datepickerfragment. But i have no idea of what i should put in the show method

Comment: How is it possible! I saw your solution. If you create fragment by importing "android.support.v4.app.Fragment " then you need to pass "getSupportFragmentManager()", i mean "date.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "Date Picker");" If you use getFragmentManager() then IDE will also give error. pls check your solution again.

Comment: @sayern . hi, exactly im using a api >14 then i changed the android.support.v4.app.fragment to the other one (I cant remember the name right now). So, after that change in use the getfragmentmanager.. In other words my mistake was import the wrong library :D